# Is it possible to do string substitution based on pair list in another column? (Substituting multiple before-after value pairs for a range)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, substitution, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have a huge list of items in colA, and wish to substitute all instances of the substrings found if colB, with colC, why does this not work?

```
=arrayformula(substitute(A1:A, B1:B, C1:C))
```

colB and colC are of the same size, and it's large. This is really just to avoid having to do all the manual ctrl+h, or have a long-winded nested `substitute(substitute(substitute(...` formula

Comment: Can you link a demo workbook with example input and showing the output you’re seeing vs your desired output?

Comment: Hi Kate, thanks for your interest in the question. The sample provided by Player0 is quite ideal, but you can see the my comments there for what's lacking.

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, B2:B)&"$",
 VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B2:B)), B2:C, 2*
 SIGN(ROW(A2:A)), 0)&""), A2:A))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hi Player0, thanks for the answer. This works pretty much as intended, except it only replaces colA if it matches colB entirely, such that xxx doesn't become rrx, which is what I wish for. Also, I believe this method would be limited by the 50000 char count limit if colA is excessively large in size or have very lengthy content in the cells.

Comment: for `xxx` to become `rrx` try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B2:B),
 VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B2:B)), B2:C, 2*
 SIGN(ROW(A2:A)), 0)&""), A2:A))`